# Is there any difference between laminal postalveolar ʃ and laminal flat postalveolar ʃ˖

Tags: phonology

Lithuanian language has laminal flat postalveolar and Maastrichtian Limburgish has laminal postalveolar. Are they any different, or just the same sound

Answer (score 2):

If someone claims that 
Lithuanian has a laminal flat postalveolar and Maastrichtian Limburgish has a laminal postalveolar, I would ask how they made that decision, and what that means (in particular, what does it mean to omit the term "flat" in describing Maastrichian?).

[Gussenhoven & Aarts](http://gep.ruhosting.nl/carlos/gussenhoven_aarts.pdf) describes the phonetics of Maastrichtian, saying this about the post-alveolars.

> /c,ʃ,ʒ,ɲ/  are  pre-palatal,  articulated  with  the  blade  of  the 
>   tongue  against  the  post-alveolar  place  of  articulation,  the 
>   tip  being  held  down.  As  is  the  case  in  the  standard
>   language,  /c/   may  be  interpreted   as  /tj/,  since  the 
>   sequence  /t/-/j/   occurring   across morpheme  boundaries  will  be
>   /c/,  just  as /n/-/j/  and /s/-/j/  will  be /ɲ/  and  /ʃ/, 
>   respectively. Analogously,  /ʒ/ would  be  /zj/  in  this  analysis, 
>   even  though  /ʒ/  is  always  morpheme-internal.

They do not say that the sounds are laminal. Ladefoged & Maddieson defines laminal thusly:

> Laminal sounds are made with the part of the tongue that has its
>   center, when the tongue is at rest, immediately below the center of
>   the alveolar ridge. The laminal area extends forward to about 2 mm
>   behind the tip of the tongue, and backward to a point about 2 mm
>   behind the point on the tongue below the center of the alveolar ridge.

Either the person who claimed that Maastrichtian has laminals made a leap from what Gussenhoven & Aarts said, or they have some independent evidence (The G&A claim is rather minimal, not implying a detailed articulatory study).

Ambrazas et al. (1997) in *Lithuanian Grammar* provide minimal phonetic detail and zero experimental results. They say that the language has *tʃ, dʒ, ʃ, ʒ* and that consonants can be "soft (palatalized) or hard (non-palatalized, velar or velarised)", saying that

> In the production of soft consonants the non-front articulatory focus
>   moves towards the middle part of the tongue (in the cases of [[kʲ,
>   gʲ,], , [ŋʲ] – *typography modified*) or the front (middle) of
>   the tongue is additionally raised towards the hard palate (in all
>   other cases). The hard (non-palatalized) consonants (especially [ɫ ʃ
>   ʒ]) are characterized not only by the absence of palatalization, but
>   also by velarisation, i.e. by raising of the back part of the tongue
>   towards the soft palate (velum). Besides, the hard [ʃ ʒ] are slightly
>   labialized.

Again, these authors do not make the specific claims cited, so the question is what is the evidence that Lithuanian has specifically laminal consonants, flat or otherwise.

There is, as far as I know, no study showing that there are language pairs that distinguish
"laminal flat postalveolar" versus "laminal postalveolar non-flat" consonants, so I would say that the claim that claim that these two languages exemplify such a difference has not been scientifically established, or even addressed.